# Create a new column that contains a list of substrings from another column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following table with "Column1", "Column2" and "Column3"

```
Column1                                 Column2  Column3
ABC - Loading                              22   3815
ABC - Loading of Page                      49   5131
Enter -CDE - Any action with target        74   2798
Exit -CDE - Any action with target2        35   3351
ACE Wireless - loading1                    12   9910
All -ACE Wireless - Click1                 49   6060
GATE - click or touch on egh               76   6061
GATE - click or touch on plans             100  6020
HUB - loading of def                       90   4854
All -HUB - Click or Touch on poe           82   2754
```

I need to create "NewColumn" where I need to extract specific strings from a list(CDE,ACE,GATE,HUB) and lookup against "Column1" as follows:

```
Column1                                 Column2  Column3  NewColumn
ABC - Loading                              22   3815        ABC
ABC - Loading of Page                      49   5131        ABC
Enter -CDE - Any action with target        74   2798        CDE
Exit -CDE - Any action with target2        35   3351        CDE
ACE Wireless - loading1                    12   9910        ACE
All -ACE Wireless - Click1                 49   6060        ACE
GATE - click or touch on egh               76   6061        GATE
GATE - click or touch on plans             100  6020        GATE
HUB - loading of def                       90   4854        HUB
All -HUB - Click or Touch on poe           82   2754        HUB
```

Please note that the keywords looked up does not repeat.

I have tried various commands such as EXTRACT, SUBSTRING etc. But none of the commands I looked at works for my specific ask.

I am looking for guidance in RedShift SQL on how I can create "NewColumn" with the list which looks up the keyword from "Column1"

Comment: how do you define a *keyword*?

Comment: Can `column1` have more than one key word? If so, I would consider making a separate table that holds a foreign key to the table in question.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Keyword is from the list - CDE,ACE,GATE,HUB

Comment: @RyanWilson There are no repetitions of the keywords from the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find the first occurrence that matches one of the values in the list given in the question.

```
select
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    regexp_substr(Column1, 'CDE|ACE|GATE|HUB') AS NewColumn
from
    your_table;
```

***EDIT:*** To accomodate @TimBiegeleisen

```
select
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    regexp_substr(
        Column1,
        (SELECT LIST_AGG(item, '|') FROM table_of_codes)
    ) AS NewColumn
from
    your_table;
```

Or...

```
select
    your_table.Column1,
    your_table.Column2,
    your_table.Column3,
    table_of_codes.item
from
    your_table
inner join
    table_of_codes
        on yourTable.col3 LIKE '%' + table_of_codes.item + '%'
;
```

Or many such variations.

*(Where the table `table_of_codes` holds one row per code you are searching for.)*

Comment: Based on the comments under my answer, `Column1` is guaranteed to have one and only one matching code.  Therefore, your regex alternation is not necessary.  It also presents a maintenance problem, because you are storing business logic inside a SQL query.

Comment: You should be storing the matching codes in a separate table, and then joining to find out if there is an actual match.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - The list of positive matches is needed if there is the possibility of a false positive match.  As per my comment on your answer : `'OOPS GATE - click or touch on plans'` will return `OOPS` rather than `GATE` unless you white list the positive matches...